# How can I get list/array with menus from the admin panel in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-admin

I tried to get list of menus (left sidebar: Posts, Media, Pages...) in admin panel without success.

I want to take all the menus or only the custom (additional) menus in the admin panel.

I made couple of tests with `global $menu`, `$GLOBALS['menu']`, `get_registered_nav_menus()`... but no have any information in.

Any idea?

Comment: there is a site for WordPress developement questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: I found the answer of my question. I should use the `admin_menu` hook when using the `global $menu`.

Comment: @EvtimKirov You can also post that as an answer to your own question for reference for future developers with the same problem…